# Do you know how to send an order from a fragment to a class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I am creating an app which uses a fragment.

Say you have an *Activity* and a *Fragment*.

*Activity* calls the *Fragment* and if I press one of the positive/negative buttons on it, I want to send an order from the *Fragment* to the *Activity* to call up the camera.

So it will once return to the *Activity* and then it calls up the camera.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: create an interface, implement it in Activity, call it in fragment

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in the activity like

```
 void openCamera(){
//write open camera code here
  }
```

Just call the open camera  (YourActivityClassname)getActivity().openCamera();

For example, your activity name is MyActivity the code is :

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).openCamera();
```

call from Fragment

Answer (score 0):

There are possible solutions that I can think of. First one is using an interface and second one which I can think of is using viewmodel. Once you press positive or negative you can update your viewmodel from fragment and can listen it inside Activity or fragment which ever you are using. But I think for this interface will be perfect as you want to listen it into activity and could have used viewmodel approach if you were doing fragment to fragment transaction.